# file mode in .cs file in ranorex

Tags: c#, vb.net, ui-automation, functional-testing, ranorex

I am new to automation testing tool Ranorex. Evaluating ranorex for the upcoming projects in our organization.

Once We are done with the recording sessions in ranorex two files are generated, one is for user to change code file and one is auto generated by ranorex.

In that .cs file on clicking right click we get file mode where inside that we have multiple options like BAT, C++.net, java, xml, HTML, coco, php etc.

**What is the use of that language selection in file mode. whereas scripting in ranorex is found to be only C# and vb.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ranorex File Mode is just to be able to change the editor color scheme (text color is based on keywords and code syntax).

Usually, file content type is determined by the file extension.

This option is more useful when file content can't be determined using the file extension.  For example, this option can be used to tell Ranorex editor that a .dat file containing xml content in a particular project.

Comment: I forgot to mention, a Ranorex project can contain any type of file/script and the Ranorex editor can be used to edit other file types.  In our projects, we use Ranorex to edit deployment scripts (batch files) and include them directly inside our Ranorex project for convenience.